# buildozer not able to convert my kivy file into an apk file in google collab

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

```
[INFO]:    Downloading openssl
[INFO]:    -> directory context /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi- 
v7a/packages/openssl
[DEBUG]:   -> running basename https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1m.tar.gz
[DEBUG]:    openssl-1.1.1m.tar.gz
[DEBUG]:   Downloading openssl from https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1m.tar.gz
[DEBUG]:   -> running rm -f .mark-openssl-1.1.1m.tar.gz
[INFO]:    Downloading openssl from https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1m.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1262, in <module>

urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Download failed: HTTP Error 404: Not Found; retrying in 1 second(s)...Download failed: HTTP Error 404: Not Found; retrying in 2 second(s)...Download failed: HTTP Error 404: Not Found; retrying in 4 second(s)...Download failed: HTTP Error 404: Not Found; retrying in 8 second(s)...# Command failed: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=spamdetector', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3,kivy,nltk,pickle,python-for-android,libffi', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page Not Found
Sorry, but the link you gave does not exist.

https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1m.tar.gz

but
https://www.openssl.org/source/old/index.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In the file ***buildozer.spec***, you can **temporarily** switch the branch of python-for-android from ***master*** to ***develop*** <strike>(where they have just updated the OpenSSL version from `1.1.1m` to `1.1.1w`, but it has not been officially released yet)</strike>. Something like this:

```
# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
# p4a.branch = master
p4a.branch = develop
```

EDIT: The OpenSSL's version in the master branch is now updated to `1.1.1w`.

Answer (score 0):

The link https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1m.tar.gz was offline yesterday, but now it's back on. It's already possible to run the code with no problem.